# H1 and the Header HTML5

Tags: html5

Should I put the `<h1>` tag inside the `<header>` section (HTML5) or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The h1 header can appear in any block element such as:*

- `<main>`, `<article>` and `<div>`
- `<article>`, `<header>` and `<footer>`
- The list goes on and on... and there's no right or wrong.

You should structure your site in a way that it easy to administrate, Google, Bing and Users really don't care about your markup, why? because why should they... its the end results they care about.

In regards of Google not seeing your content correctly either by the Cache or Fetch test then its likely something to do with your CSS, not the HTML.